# Get information from the clicked element in Jquery / Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, css

Good night, I will be quick in my explanation. I need to get information from the element clicked on the site, for example, I want to get the css information from the elements I clicked, however, they can be div, button, li, etc. Getting the information is not a problem, the problem is being to identify which was the element that received the click, because it can have any id or any class. They are not fixed ids or classes. I'm using this js code but it's not working. He's giving me the html of the whole body.

```
$("*").click(function() {
    console.log($(this).html());
});
```

Can someone help me please?

Att

Comment: `$(this)` inside your Event function is the jQuery Element that was clicked. `$(this).css()` gives you the CSS. The body is also an Element you get with `*`.

Comment: You need to prevent bubbling

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if I don't get you wrong, you can view the properties of any element I click on the body thanks to event bubbling.

```js
document.getElementById("body").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  console.log(e.target)
})
```

```html
<body id="body">
  <div class="container">
    <div>
      <h5>
        <button>
                    ı am a button
                </button>
      </h5>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="container-fluid">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="#">link</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">link</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">link</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">link</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">link</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>

</body>
```